# Does `Random.nextString()` take O(n) time in Scala?

Tags: scala, random, time-complexity, big-o

When calling `nextString()` from the built-in `scala.util.Random` library, what time does it take to run? Is that *O(n)*?

Comment: Please explain the downvote.

Comment: have you looked at the source code? http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_1_final/src/library/scala/util/Random.scala#L83

Comment: Yes, I did. `safeChar` should take O(1) time, but not sure about the other.

Comment: which other? `List.fill` ?

Comment: Precisely. I couldn't find any infos on the internet.

Comment: maybe on Scala reddit you get more responses. If you decide to post it there, and you get a nice answer, please share it :) https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/. Or maybe check this post https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/4cut31/does_scala_have_a_slack_channel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's O(n).  It can't be any lower, because it creates a new string and that has O(n) cost.  It shouldn't be any higher, because creating a random number is O(1) and that's enough to pick a character or word or something.  And in practice it's actually O(n).

The constant factor is pretty high, though, due to how it's implemented.  If it is important to you to make random strings really fast, you should get your own high-performance random number generator and pack chars into a char array.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find anything on Scala docs, but from the [source code](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_1_final/src/library/scala/util/Random.scala#L83):

```
def nextString(length: Int) = {
        def safeChar() = {
          val surrogateStart: Int = 0xD800
          val res = nextInt(surrogateStart - 1) + 1
          res.toChar
        }

        List.fill(length)(safeChar()).mkString
}
```

I would say O(n), assuming O(1) from `nextInt()`, on the length of the string asked